# Under what conditions on $a,b,c$ is the sum $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ strictly greater than $(a+b+c)^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was solving a problem earlier and if this was true in general it would've made everything much easier, but it's not. So I thought it would be interesting to know when exactly it is true.

Comment: One of the cases in which this holds is $a,b =0$ and $c\gt1$.

Comment: The inequality holds $\forall \quad a,b,c\gt 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ is homogeneous of order $3$ while $(a+b+c)^2$ is homogeneous of order $2$.  So for any $a,b,c>0$, the statement will be true for $(ta,tb,tc)$ if $t$ is sufficiently large and false if $t>0$ is sufficiently small.  The boundary between the two regions is a certain surface.  Here is a picture of it.

[image]